# Accessing a script inside image, GitlLab CI

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

My config.yml :

```
stages:
  - collect
image: 
  name: usd3221/log-stats:latest
  entrypoint: [""]

default:
 tags:
  - local

job:
  stage: collect
  script:
    - pwd
    #- ruby run_log.rb ${argone} ${arg_2}
```

I am using a custom image `log-stats` which has the `run_log.rb` inside the $WORKDIR. My question is, how can I run this script which is inside the image directory on my gitlab runner and pass the arguments from my git env vars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the image fields, change the `entrypoint` to the script you want to execute i.e:

```
entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "ruby run_log.rb ${argone} ${argtwo}"]
```

Assuming the `$WORKDIR` in your image contains the `ruby run_log.rb`.